# Stored procedure history and what application is calling it?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I was given the batch work to research our 200 stored procedures and find out a bunch of different information about them. Is there anyway in SQL Server 2012 to pull execution history on stored procedures? Also is there anyway to tell what application might be calling the stored procedure? Even an IP address would be helpful because we have several server that do various processing.

Any information you can provide me about this would be extremely helpful. I am relatively new to this type of thing in SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway in SQL Server 2012 to pull execution history on stored procedures?

You can use <kbd>[sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx)</kbd> to find stored procedure execution times plus most time consuming, CPU intensive ones as well

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    d.object_id, d.database_id, 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'proc name', 
    d.cached_time, d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,
    d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],
    d.last_elapsed_time, d.execution_count
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d
ORDER BY
    [total_worker_time] DESC;
```

> Also is there anyway to tell what application might be calling the stored procedure? Even an IP address would be helpful because we have several server that do various processing.

The answer to both the above questions is <kbd>NO</kbd>, unless you monitor them real time using below query. You can run below query using SQL Server Agent as per your predefined intervals and capture the output in a table. Further please note that this gives you individual statements inside a stored procedure.

```
select
    r.session_id,
    s.login_name,
    c.client_net_address,
    s.host_name,
    s.program_name,
    st.text
from 
    sys.dm_exec_requests r
inner join 
    sys.dm_exec_sessions s on r.session_id = s.session_id
left join 
    sys.dm_exec_connections c on r.session_id = c.session_id
outer apply 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) st
```

Comment: Thanks! I've come across the procedure stats which are somewhat helpful. How can I find a list of all scheduled store procedure within SQL?

Comment: What does Scheduled mean ?could you please update question

Comment: Planned executions

Comment: you could run procedure stats DMV and see the last run  times